# Haskell Image Processing - compile-time errors

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I've been struggling to get this code running. The code is basically supposed to be a convolution for image processing...

```
import Codec.Picture

-- Apply a convolution filter to an image
applyFilter :: Image PixelRGB8 -> [[Float]] -> Image PixelRGB8
applyFilter img filter = pixelMap (applyPixelFilter filter) img

-- Apply the convolution filter to a single pixel
applyPixelFilter :: [[Float]] -> PixelRGB8 -> PixelRGB8
applyPixelFilter filter (PixelRGB8 r g b) = PixelRGB8 (fromIntegral (truncate newR)) (fromIntegral (truncate newG)) (fromIntegral (truncate newB))
 where
  (newR, newG, newB) = applyFilterToPixel filter (fromIntegral r, fromIntegral g, fromIntegral b)

-- Apply the convolution filter to a single pixel (RGB values as Floats)
applyFilterToPixel :: [[Float]] -> (Float, Float, Float) -> (Float, Float, Float)
applyFilterToPixel filter (r, g, b) = (newR, newG, newB)
 where
  (newR, newG, newB) = applyFilterToChannel filter (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) $ zip3 (concat filter) [r, r, r, r] [g, g, g, g] [b, b, b, b]

-- Apply the convolution filter to a single channel of a pixel
applyFilterToChannel :: [[Float]] -> (Float, Float, Float) -> [(Float, Float, Float, Float)] -> (Float, Float, Float)
applyFilterToChannel filter (accR, accG, accB) xs = (accR + sumR, accG + sumG, accB + sumB)
 where
  (sumR, sumG, sumB) = foldl applyFilterToRow (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) xs

-- Apply the convolution filter to a single row
applyFilterToRow :: (Float, Float, Float) -> (Float, Float, Float, Float) -> (Float, Float, Float)
applyFilterToRow (accR, accG, accB) (filterVal, r, g, b) = (accR + filterVal * r, accG + filterVal * g, accB + filterVal * b)

-- Example usage
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let inputFile = "input.png"
      outputFile = "output.png"
      boxBlurFilter = [[1/9, 1/9, 1/9],
                       [1/9, 1/9, 1/9],
                       [1/9, 1/9, 1/9]]
  result <- readImage inputFile
  case result of
    Left err -> putStrLn $ "Error reading image: " ++ err
    Right dynamicImage ->
      case dynamicImage of
        ImageRGB8 img -> do
          let outputImage = applyFilter img boxBlurFilter
          savePngImage outputFile outputImage
          putStrLn $ "Output image saved as " ++ outputFile
        _ -> putStrLn "Unsupported image format."
```

I have a vague idea of what's going on, but I'm struggling to find a solution.

These are the errors:

```
Couldn't match expected type: 
[Float] -> [(Float, Float, Float, Float)] with actual type: [(Float, Float, Float)]

Couldn't match expected type: 
(Float, Float, Float) with actual type: (a3, b0, c0, d0)

Couldn't match expected type ‘DynamicImage’ with actual type ‘Image PixelRGB8’
```

Comment: You are calling library function `zip3` with 4 arguments. As its name hints to, it is supposed to take only 3 arguments. BTW it is slightly error prone to have code lines so long that you have use the horizontal ruler to hide the beginning of the line in order to see its end.

Comment: Note that if you meant to use `zip4`, unlike `zip3` that's not part of the Haskell Prelude, so you'll have to import it: `import  Data.List (zip4)`

Comment: But I would advise against using `zip4`, or indeed tuples with more than 3 elements generally. Even 3 is seldom a good idea, normally it's better to make descriptive record types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type:
[Float] -> [(Float, Float, Float, Float)] with actual type: [(Float, Float, Float)]
```

this is typical of a function called with the wrong count of arguments. You are calling library function `zip3` with 4 arguments. I suppose you actually want to call `zip4`. But unlike `zip3`, `zip4` is not part of the Prelude, so you have to import it explicitly like this:

```
import  Data.List (zip4)
```

If you have to use an `import` clause anyway, you might as well replace `foldl` with `foldl'` for the usual efficiency reasons (thunk avoidance). Hence:

```
import  Data.List (zip4, foldl')
```

and then:

```
  where
    (newR, newG, newB) = applyFilterToChannel filter (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)  $
                           zip4 (concat filter) [r, r, r, r]
                                                [g, g, g, g]
                                                [b, b, b, b]
```

Regarding the second error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type:
(Float, Float, Float) with actual type: (a3, b0, c0, d0)
```

you just need to use a triplet of zeros as the starting accumulator, instead of a quadruplet:

```
(sumR, sumG, sumB) = foldl' applyFilterToRow (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) xs
```

Regarding the third error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘DynamicImage’ with actual type ‘Image PixelRGB8’
```

you are simply missing a suitable type converter. You can ask the specialized search engine [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Image+PixelRGB8+-%3E+DynamicImage&scope=set%3Astackage) which one.
Hence:

```
savePngImage outputFile (ImageRGB8 outputImage)
```

Overall, the following code seems to work:

```
import  Data.List (zip4, foldl')
import  Codec.Picture

-- Apply a convolution filter to an image
applyFilter :: Image PixelRGB8 -> [[Float]] -> Image PixelRGB8
applyFilter img filter = pixelMap (applyPixelFilter filter) img

-- Apply the convolution filter to a single pixel
applyPixelFilter :: [[Float]] -> PixelRGB8 -> PixelRGB8
applyPixelFilter filter (PixelRGB8 r g b) = PixelRGB8
                                               (fromIntegral (truncate newR))
                                               (fromIntegral (truncate newG))
                                               (fromIntegral (truncate newB))
  where
    (newR, newG, newB) = applyFilterToPixel filter
                             (fromIntegral r, fromIntegral g, fromIntegral b)

-- Apply the convolution filter to a single pixel (RGB values as Floats)
applyFilterToPixel :: [[Float]] -> (Float, Float, Float) -> (Float, Float, Float)
applyFilterToPixel filter (r, g, b) = (newR, newG, newB)
  where
    (newR, newG, newB) = applyFilterToChannel filter (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)  $
                           zip4 (concat filter) [r, r, r, r]
                                                [g, g, g, g]
                                                [b, b, b, b]

-- Apply the convolution filter to a single channel of a pixel
applyFilterToChannel :: [[Float]] -> (Float, Float, Float) ->
                        [(Float, Float, Float, Float)] -> (Float, Float, Float)
applyFilterToChannel filter (accR, accG, accB) xs =
    (accR + sumR, accG + sumG, accB + sumB)
        where
            (sumR, sumG, sumB) = foldl' applyFilterToRow (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) xs

-- Apply the convolution filter to a single row
applyFilterToRow :: (Float, Float, Float) -> (Float, Float, Float, Float) ->
                    (Float, Float, Float)
applyFilterToRow (accR, accG, accB) (filterVal, r, g, b) = (accR + filterVal * r,
                                                            accG + filterVal * g,
                                                            accB + filterVal * b)

-- Example usage
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let inputFile  = "input.png"
      outputFile = "output.png"
      boxBlurFilter = [[1/9, 1/9, 1/9],
                       [1/9, 1/9, 1/9],
                       [1/9, 1/9, 1/9]]
  result <- readImage inputFile
  case result of
    Left err -> putStrLn $ "Error reading image: " ++ err
    Right dynamicImage ->
      case dynamicImage of
        ImageRGB8 img -> do
          let outputImage = applyFilter img boxBlurFilter
          savePngImage outputFile (ImageRGB8 outputImage)
          putStrLn $ "Output image saved as " ++ outputFile

        _ -> putStrLn "Unsupported image format."
```

Please note that I have folded the extra-long code lines, in order to make the code readable on SO (and easier to read and maintain).

Comment: Live Long & Prosper